# Move focus to next input on mouse click in jquery autocomplete item

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have a [jQuery autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) attached to a textbox, when I select an `autocomplete` item by pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> it focuses the next input. but when I select the item by mouse `click` it focuses the first input instead of the next input.

My inputs are ASP.Net inputs and each have a `tabindex`.

So far what I have tried is

jQuery Code :

```js
$("#txtArea").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        var outputList = LoadAutocompleteResult(areaNameList, request.term);
        response(outputList);
    },
    close: function () {
        var ti = $("#txtArea").attr('tabindex') + 1;
        $('[tabindex=' + ti + ']').focus();
    }
});
```

also tried the following

```js
$("#txtArea").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        var outputList = LoadAutocompleteResult(areaNameList, request.term);
        response(outputList);
    },
    select: function () {
        var ti = $("#txtArea").attr('tabindex') + 1;
        $('[tabindex=' + ti + ']').focus();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most JavaScript engines will treat:

```
var ti = $("#txtArea").attr('tabindex') + 1;
```

as concatenation, not addition, so the `ti` variable has `"1"` appended to it's initial value. The solution is to parse `ti` to a number before attempting to increment it, or to use an operator specifically designed to increment it (which will convert the string to a number in the process).

```
var ti = parseInt($("#txtArea").attr('tabindex'), 10) + 1;
```

or

```
var attr = $("#txtArea").attr('tabindex'),
    ti = attr++; // caveat here is that, if ti = 1, attr will be 2
```

otherwise you'll be trying to focus `$('[tabindex=11]')`, instead of `$('[tabindex=2]')`;

### Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XfPen/